# How to access ms sql server 2008 in c?

Tags: sql-server, c

I know little about sql server access, and all googled out for sql server accessing are using
C# or php like language.

Is there a good step by step about how to set up sdk and write an start program in c
to access sql server database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

1. [ODBC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa198030%28SQL.80%29.aspx)
2. SQLServer's [DB-Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa936940%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

If your application has a fairly simple DB interface (mostly common insert, update, delete, select commands), I would go for ODBC because of portability issues.

Do keep in mind that in order to use DB-Library you might need to get DLL's from older versions of SQLServer, since it's been deprecated in 2008.